# Real analysis - proving that sets are closed

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the following sets are closed.

(1) $S=\{x \in \mathbb R : \sin x \le \cos x\}$

(2) $T=\{x \in \mathbb R : ax \leq \lvert x\rvert\}$ $(a \in \mathbb R^n $ is fixed)

My attempt

(1) Let $f(x)=$sin$x$ and $g(x)=$cos$x$ and $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)=$sin$x$-cos$x$

sin$x$-cos$x$ $\leq 0$

I think from this condition, we have to find a set (i.e. the preimage set $h^{-1}(S)$) which is closed, in order to conclude that $S$ is closed. But I am stuck with finding such preimage set.

Any hint with (2) would be appreciated too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple : the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function is a closed set. From basic knowledge and examples of continuous functions (trigonometric functions, polynomials etc.) this problem is easy to work out.

For example, note that $S = \{x \in \mathbb R : h(x) \in [0,\infty)\}$ where $h(x) = \cos x - \sin x$. So, $S = h^{-1} ([0,\infty))$, and hence is the preimage of a closed set $[0,\infty)$ under the continuous function $h$. Hence we are done i.e. $S$ is closed.

Similarly, $T = g^{-1}([0,\infty))$, where $g(x) = |x| - ax$. The same logic as above applies to get $T$ is closed, since $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close.

Observe that $S=h^{-1}((-\infty,0])$. Since $h$ is continuous and $(-\infty,0]$ is closed, $S$ should be closed.

As for hint of $(b)$, similarly, note that $g(x)=ax-|x|$ is continuous and either $(-\infty,0]$ or $[0,\infty)$ is closed.